# Wifi with rt2800usb dead after 20.04 LTS upgrade

Tags: networking, wireless, usb

I have a Tenda W322U v2.0 USB Wifi adaptor which worked just fine on an old Edubuntu OS have been running for years. How having upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Now of course the wifi is dead. I get the following:

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:3072 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3072 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

sudo lshw -class network:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:2
       logical name: wlxc83a35cf5510
       serial: c8:3a:35:cf:55:10
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb
driverversion=5.8.0-43-generic firmware=0.36 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
      wlxc83a35cf5510:
        optional: true
        access-points:
            "mariqLan":
                    password: "password"
        dhcp4: true
```

I managed to get the light to go on, on the stick itself by command:

```
sudo ip link set dev wlxc83a35cf5510 up
```

ip  link:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:25:91:e6:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0
4: wls3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1f:3c:4b:68:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp3s0
5: wlxc83a35cf5510: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:3a:35:cf:55:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

On the UI, the 'USB Wifi Off' remains so no matter how I try to turn it on via UI.

Also:

```
sudo dkms status
rtl8192eu, 1.0, 5.8.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed

uname -r
5.8.0-43-generic

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rt2800usb              32768  0
rt2x00usb              24576  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib             131072  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              65536  3 rt2800usb,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib

dmesg | grep wlxc83a35cf5510
[  743.635390] rt2800usb 2-2:1.0 wlxc83a35cf5510: renamed from wlan0
```

Please help! ;-)

Comment: What is the interface wls1? Are you trying to run two conflicting wireless devices at the same time? Your netplan file says Network Manager is in charge but then adds wireless details and the interesting 'optional'. In what way is it optional? How will you start or stop an optional wireless interface? Please edit your question to clarify. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi. The notebook has built-in wifi which is not working - hence I replaced it by using the USB-wifi stick. This used to work well with previous Edubuntu distribution of about 5 years ago. But since I am now upgraded to 20.04 LTS, the USB-wifi won't connect. wls3 is the built-in. Should I not use the yaml specification to set wifi?

Comment: PS...I am able to manually bring up the wifi by: sudo ip link set dev wlxc83a35cf5510 up

Comment: ...and then I can scan the wifi SSID's with: sudo iw wlxc83a35cf5510 scan

Comment: ...but the netplan does not seem to be applied to bring up and authenticate the wifi connection. Please advise....Much appreciated.

Comment: Let's find some details about the non-working device. Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `dmesg | grep wls` Thanks.

Comment: Hi - here are the results requested: $ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4227] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation ThinkPad T60/R60e/X60s/R61 [8086:1011]
 Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
 Kernel modules: iwl3945

Comment: and... $ dmesg | grep wls
[   18.362717] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0 wls3: renamed from wlan0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reduce or eliminate any possible interference, I suggest that you blacklist the driver for the evidently malfunctioning internal device. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r iwl3945
echo “blacklist iwl3945”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Remove the USB wireless device.

Next, restore netplan to its default state:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Restart NM:

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Reinsert the USB wireless device. Is there any improvement?

Comment: Thank you soo much! You are brilliant. ;-)